# How does one access the current SceneDelegate from a XCUIApplication object?

Tags: swift, xcode, xcuitest

I went through the official documentation and the autocomplete options in Xcode but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

UI Tests are not supposed to provide you application code access. You test them as a user would (black box testing).

On current screen,

1. find a button with label "Get Started"
2. Tap on it
3. Swipe Up etc.

You would exercise the app as a user would use it, tap on A, wait for B to appear on screen etc.

Comment: Okay so how am I supposed to have application code access while navigating through it in a way that allows me to use XCTest?

Comment: @thanat0sis That's a different question. UI tests and unit tests run separately not together.

Comment: Are you telling me it's theoretically impossible?

Comment: From UI Tests target, you don't get app code's access - that's it. Unit Tests target will allow you to test whatever part of code you want to exercise (model or UI code).

Comment: XCUITests using SIRI Codebase + Accessibility codebase in the background. You can access the app using bundle Identifier, and that activates sessions for App. Your App is a black box you can send something, and you get something in return without knowing things actually happening in the background